# How to authenticate users before downloading files?

Tags: php

For example, if users want to download /webroot/files/bigimage.jpg, they are given a URL www.domain.com/download.php?filename=bigimage.jpg. Then,

1. How to prevent unauthenticated users
   to access the file bigimage.jpg?
2. If an authenticated user visits that
   URL, I want to trigger the download
   behavior of browsers (e.g., in IE,
   show the dialog with "Open", "Save"
   and "Cancel" buttons) instead of
   displaying the image in browsers.
   How to do this?

EDIT: 
Make the question more clearer.

I am using LAMP stack. For Q1, I am not asking how to do authentication, I am asking how to prevent users access the file directly. Also, reading contents of the whole file and echo them is resource extensive. Is there better solution?

Comment: which server are you using? Apache? If so, .htaccess might be a good starting point, together with basic http authentication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First step, drop a .htaccess file in the folder with the image that says "deny from all".  This will prevent anyone from access the file even if they know the folder.

Then, you write use a PHP function like this

```
$file = 'path/to/folder' . $filename;
//Make sure you check that $filename does not contain ".." for security
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
} else {
    //Show error message
}
```

You should be checking session variables to see if the user is logged and has a role that can download this.  This code will also force download of the image than show it.

Comment: I couldn't get this code to work. The file downloaded, but I couldn't open the file. I removed `ob_clean()` and now it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use sessions.
2. Set the header's content META tag to binary so browsers won't try to handle the file on their own.

   header('Content-Type: application/binary');

Answer (score 1):

use something like this for only images in your .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/uploads/([0-9]+/.*)\(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ /root/image.php?img=$2.$3 [L]
</IfModule>
```

or for any filetype something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/uploads/([0-9]+/.*)\.* /root/image.php?img=$2.$3 [L]
</IfModule>
```

then in your PHP something like this:

```
<?php
// server link to wordpress installation when using Wordpress
require_once('/root/wp-config.php');
if( is_user_logged_in() ):

  $file = '/root/wp-content/uploads/'.$_GET['img'];

  if (file_exists($file)) 
  {
    $ftype = 'application/octet-stream'; 
    $finfo = @new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME); 
    $fres = @$finfo->file($file); 
    if (is_string($fres) && !empty($fres)) { 
       $ftype = $fres; 
    } 

    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header('Content-Type: ' . $ftype);
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
    header('Content-Disposition: filename='.basename($file));

    flush();
    readfile($file);

  }
  else
  {
    header("Location: //media.vet.uu.nl/ziekteleerboek", 404);
  }

else:  

 auth_redirect();

endif;

die();
?>
```

Got this to work nicely for a website of mine.

You may be able to speed up the code by allowing caching.

This way will not force downloading tho, which worked just fine for me.

For forcing download use:

```
header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='.basename($file));
```

This works for most browsers and filetypes.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a cookie in the user's browser once they authenticate with setcookie().  Your download script could check $_COOKIE for an authentication string.  If you want to get fancy about it you could have some sort of unique auth string for each user and check against a database.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use Apache as the webserver. Try to use some http auth as an option. This is great tutoril showing how to set the things up to work properly http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/auth.html