# Login session for pdf files

Tags: php, session

I have html, pdf, doc files in a web folder. I have a php file that list out all the files in my folder. I am checking html files for login sessions. If logged in the html file is shown if not it will redirect to login prompt. How do I do this for PDF and doc file.

If I have direct URL for pdf or doc I can open the file. I would like to restrict it by checking the login session. Is this possible?

Something like if click [www.mydomainexample.com/test.pdf](http://www.mydomainexample.com/test.pdf) - This should check login session and not open pdf automatically. Same way:

[www.mydomainexample.com/test.doc](http://www.mydomainexample.com/test.doc) - should check login session and not download doc file automatically.

E.g:

webserver root folder has the following files:

1. login.php
2. listoffiles.php
3. abc.html
4. cde.html
5. fgh.html
6. first.pdf
7. second.pdf
8. third.pdf
9. first.doc
10. second.doc
11. third.doc

All the html files have session check. How do I check login session for pdf and doc for the file structure.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add some code to your question, so we can better understand your question and possibly identify the issue(s). It is recommended to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @chade_ : I don't know what do to where to start to check pdf and doc file session. I know how to check html or any other php file login session as I have written the code.

Answer (score 0):

Once user get logged in to your site set $_SESSION['user_id'] of logged in user and on doc url put this code

```
 if(empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
// code to send user on login page
  }
```

Comment: it is just doc file or pdf: How can I put php code in it? chrome open PDF and doc is downloaded automatically. It is direct URL: www.mydomain.com/test.pdf

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903729/how-to-authenticate-users-before-downloading-files
check this url

Comment: This works file for different folder not on files (php, pdf doc) on same folders

Comment: you have to create .htaccess file with rule which redirect user to php scripts if user is going to access file or image. and on that php script you have to put above mention check.

Comment: read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124109/protect-pdf-docs-from-being-directly-accessed-in-url?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need the answer, but one of the ways you can handle this is by using an .htaccess file if your using an Apache server. Put an .htaccess in the folder with the doc and pdf files. You can then use something like the code block below to deny access to those file types. It should give a 403 Forbidden error.

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
<Files ~ "\.(doc|pdf)$">
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Additionally, you can then setup a PHP script that lets you load the files through the script OR you can do some additional work with HTACCESS file that checks for HTTP Referrer header is from your domain before loading the file.

```
$filename = 'readme.pdf';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
    readfile($filename);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

actually i was use this type but i had used [tcpdf](https://tcpdf.org/examples/)

and you can also set on this file use your PHP code and after you can set as download or displaying in browser.

it's very easy for making thousands pdf.

```
session_start();
//rest of your code and then...
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    enter code here
     }
```

Comment: where do you want to me to put php code. It is just a doc. As mentioned in the question it is a direct url for the file.

Comment: you will download this code and after just check few example in your local after you will get more idea. and php curl using you can download multiple pdfs.

Comment: I don't think you have got the idea. Can you please read the question again. Thanks!